# Associate many child tables to a parent table

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I will do my best to lay this out in text.  Essentially, we have an application that tracks actions performed by users.  Each action has it's own table since each action has different parameters that need to be stored.  This allows us to store those extra attributes and run analytics on the actions across multiple or single users rather easily.  The actions are not really associated with each other other than by what user performed these actions.

Example:

- **ActionTableA**  Id | UserId | AttributeA | AttributeB
- **ActionTableB**  Id | UserId | AttributeC | AttributeD | AttributeE
- **ActionTableC**  Id | UserId | AttributeF

Next, we need to allocate a value to each action performed by the user and keep a running total of those values.

Example:
**ValueTable:**   Id | UserId | Value | ActionType | ActionId

What would be the best way to link the value in the value table to the actual action performed?  We know the action type (A, B, C) - but from a SQL design perspective, I cannot see a good way to have an indexed relationship between the Values of the actions in the ActionsTable and the actual actions themselves.  The only thing that makes sense would be to modify the ValueTable to the following:

**ValueTable**

Id | UserId | Value | ActionType | ActionAId(FK Nullable) | ActionBId(FK Nullable) | ActionCId(FK Nullable)

But the problem I have with this that only one of the 3 actionTableId columns would have a value, the rest would be Null.  Additionally, as action types are added, the columns in the value table would too.  Lastly, to programatically find the data, I would either a) have to check the ActionType to get the appropriate column for the Id or b) scan the row and pick the non-null actionId.

Is there a better way/design or is this just 'the way it is' for this particular issue.

**EDIT**

Attached is a diagram of the above setup:

[image]

Sorry for the clarity issues, typing SQL questions is always challenging.  So I think your comment gave me an idea of something... I could have an SystemActionId table that essentially has an auto-generated value

**SystemActions**:  Id |  Type

Then, each ActionTable would have an additional FK to the SystemAction table.  Lastly, in the ValueTable - associate it to the SystemActions table as well.  This would allow us to tie values to specific actions.  I would need to join the action tables to the system actions table where

`JOIN (((SystemActions.Id = ActionTableA.Id) JOIN (SystemActions.Id = ActionTableB.Id)) JOIN (SystemActions.Id = ActionTableC.Id)`

*crappy quick sql syntax*

Is this what you were alluding to in the answer below?  A snapshot of what that could potentially look like:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but it looks like you should either have a (denormalized) value column in each action table, or have an artificial key in the value table that is keyed to by each of the seperate action tables.

Comment: I added a diagram for clarity and attempted to assimilate what you proposed - I think.  Take a look and see if I am on the right track?

Comment: Looks like the right idea, but why not collapse the ActionType column into the ActionValues table and key the various action tables directly to that?

Comment: Gotcha - I will give that a go tomorrow, thinking about this problem is preventing sleep.  I will keep this open until the morning and see how it all works out.  Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially a supertype/subtype structure, or an exclusive arc.  Attributes common to all actions bubble "up" into the supertype (the table "actions"). Columns unique to each subtype bubble "down" into the distinct subtypes.

```
create temp table actions (
  action_id integer not null,
  action_type char(1) not null check (action_type in ('a', 'b', 'c')),
  user_id integer not null, -- references users, not shown.
  primary key (action_id),
  -- Required for data integrity. See below.
  unique (action_id, action_type)
);

create temp table ActionTableA (
  action_id integer primary key,
  -- default and check constraint guarantee that only an 'a' row goes
  -- in this table.
  action_type char(1) not null default 'a' check (action_type = 'a'),
  -- FK guarantees that this row matches only an 'a' row in actions.
  -- To make this work, you need a UNIQUE constraint on these two columns
  -- in the table "actions".
  foreign key (action_id, action_type) 
    references actions (action_id, action_type),
  attributeA char(1) not null,
  attributeB char(1) not null
);

-- ActionTableB and ActionTableC are similar.

create temp table ValueTable (
  action_id integer primary key,
  action_type char(1) not null,
  -- Since this applies to all actions, FK should reference the supertype,
  -- which is the table "actions". You can reference either action_id alone, 
  -- which has a PRIMARY KEY constraint, or the pair {action_id, action_type},
  -- which has a UNIQUE constraint. Using the pair makes some kinds of 
  -- accounting queries easier and faster.
  foreign key (action_id, action_type) 
    references actions (action_id, action_type),
  value integer not null default 0 check (value >= 0)
);
```

To round this out, build updatable views that join the supertype to each subtype, and have all users use the views instead of the base tables.

Comment: +1 I have used similar approaches before. But I still wonder if there's a better way. Representing OOP data in a relational db isn't a very easy fit...

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a single table for actions, to be honest. Is there a reason (other than denormalization) for having multiple tables? Especially when it will increase the complexity of your business logic?

Are the attribute columns significant in the context of the schema? Could you compress it into an object storage column "attributes"?

```
Actions: actionID, type, attributes
```

Comment: I tried to think through this idea initially, but the data types (attributes) for each action are pretty dissimilar (and more complex than the example - a few have child tables themselves for example) and it would potentially shift the business logic complexity to the analytics side of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something similar to an Audit Trail. Can we have a simple design so that all the actions will be captured in a singe table ?

[image]

Comment: Yup - we could defiantly do something like this.  But I would really rather not lose the benefits of indexing/foreign keys inside of the database if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If the way you want it to work is that for *every time* a user performs action A you insert a new row in table ActionTableA and a row in ValueTable, and having them both linked, why not have a value column in each action table? This would work only if you want to insert a new row each time the user performs the action rather than if you want to update the value if the user performs the same action again. It seems overly complicated to have a separate table for values if it can be stored in a column. On the other hand if a "value" is a set of different pieces of data (or if you want to have all values in one place) then you do need an extra table but I would still have a foreign key column pointing from the action tables to the value table.